# Factory Girl: Set default value of transient attribute to factory

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, factory-bot

I have an FG factory that returns a complex hash, let's call it zhash, because it's defined at the end of the factories (FG loads the files alphabetically).

That hash is stored as a json string on a model (right or wrong, that's how it is). I have an ignore variable (a transient attribute) on that model's factory that allows me to set that attribute to my custom hash, but I'd like to set a default value of that ignore variable to the default for that hash factory.

e.g.

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :model do
    ignore do
      # this does not work, because the factory has not been defined.
      hash FactoryGirl.create(:zhash)
    end
  end
end

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :zhash do
    ... #return hash
  end
end
```

I could just change the name of the zhash file to `0_zhash`, but is there a FactoryGirl way to set a factory as the default value for an ignore variable?

Comment: When you say _variable_, do you mean _attribute_ to the model/object?

Comment: I mean an ignore variable. A transient attribute. It does not directly belong to the model/object. Good point, though. I updated the language.

Comment: Is this being done on a callback (before/after build/create)? If so, you can put it there. I do not know, or have experience with, setting non-associated variables with FG. Only attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :model do
    ignore do
      zhash
    end
    numeric_attribute zhash.count
  end
end
```

will not work, but

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :model do
    ignore do
      zhash
    end
    numeric_attribute { zhash.count }
  end
end
```

will

(also, "ignore" is deprecated in current factorygirl and is to be replaced by "transient")